# Encrypt the string In Typescript And Decrypt In C# using Advanced Encryption Standard Algorithm(AES)

Tags: c#, security, angular, typescript, aes

I am having struggle to implement the encryption in typescript and decryption in C#. Before posting question here, I did Google it and find some links but those links are related to JavaScript not a typescript.

[Encrypt in javascript and decrypt in C# with AES algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474899/encrypt-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-c-sharp-with-aes-algorithm)

[encrypt the text using cryptojs library in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296592/encrypt-the-text-using-cryptojs-library-in-angular2)

[How to import non-core npm modules in Angular 2 e.g. (to use an encryption library)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772710/how-to-import-non-core-npm-modules-in-angular-2-e-g-to-use-an-encryption-libra/36773274#36773274)

I followed the above links, for implementing the encryption/decryption concept in my current application.

This is the code I wrote in **myservice.ts**

```
    //import { CryptoJS } from 'node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js';
    //import 'crypto-js';
    import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';


    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("It works"), key,
        {
            keySize: 128 / 8,
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    console.log('Encrypted :' + encrypted);
    console.log('Key :' + encrypted.key);
    console.log('Salt :' + encrypted.salt);
    console.log('iv :' + encrypted.iv);
    console.log('Decrypted : ' + decrypted);
    console.log('utf8 = ' + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Before I added the above lines of code in **myservice.ts**, I added the dependency as **"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1"** in **package.json** file.

After added the above dependency in package.json, then I was restored the packages successfully. But still also CryptoJS shows error in myservice.ts like **can not found name as CryptoJS**.

Can you please tell me how to import the CryptoJS from node modules and also tell me how to encrypt the string in typescript and decrypt the same string in C# using Advanced Security Algorithm (AES)?

Pradeep

Comment: typescript is a super set of javascript. so what ever works in javascript will work in typescript.

Comment: Thanks, I know that typescript is a super set of javascript, but when added the above lines of code in my application then I got the exception as " can not found name as CryptoJS". if you want more information, please see my updated question once.

Comment: To test interoperability this might be fine, of don't use it in production like that. Pretty much everything you can do wrong cryptographically is wrong in that code.

Comment: @CodesInChaos can you please link or describe the proper way to do what the OP is trying to do.  I have the same issue i need in a production environment.  I need encrypt a JSON string in ts and decrypt it in c#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**npm instal crypto-js**

```
//Inside imports of your TS file include 
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

// Declare this key and iv values in declaration
private key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('4512631236589784');
private iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('4512631236589784');

// Methods for the encrypt and decrypt Using AES
encryptUsingAES256() {
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify("Your Json Object data or string")), this.key, {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: this.iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    console.log('Encrypted :' + encrypted);
    this.decryptUsingAES256(encrypted);
    return encrypted;
}

decryptUsingAES256(decString) {
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decString, this.key, {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: this.iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    console.log('Decrypted : ' + decrypted);
    console.log('utf8 = ' + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

}
```

**The C# code to encode or decode is here.**

```
public class encr {
    public static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText) {
        var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("4512631236589784");
        var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("4512631236589784");

        var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        var decriptedFromJavascript = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, keybytes, iv);
        return decriptedFromJavascript;
    }
    private static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        }
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }
        if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an RijndaelManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using(var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged()) {
            //Settings
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

            rijAlg.Key = key;
            rijAlg.IV = iv;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            var decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            try {
                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using(var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText)) {
                    using(var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {

                        using(var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) {
                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch {
                plaintext = "keyError";
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }

    public static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText) {
        var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("4512631236589784");
        var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("4512631236589784");

        var encryoFromJavascript = EncryptStringToBytes(plainText, keybytes, iv);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryoFromJavascript);
    }

    private static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        }
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }
        if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create a RijndaelManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using(var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged()) {
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

            rijAlg.Key = key;
            rijAlg.IV = iv;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            var encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using(var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
                using(var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                    using(var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it required to keep the same key and Iv values. as given

Comment: No, you can keep any key you want.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue. I'm using Angular 4/Angular-Cli 1.0.0. What worked for me:

```
npm install crypto-js --save
npm install @types/crypto-js --save
```

After these two commands, reference the **crypto-js** library in the **angular-cli.json** file, in the "scripts" array. In my case:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"
  ]
```

You'll notice that in the **node_modules/@types** directory, you'll have a crypto-js subdirectory. So put a reference to the **node_modules/@types/crypto-js/index.d.ts** file in your code, using a [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html), so the compliler knows that the typings file is necessary to compile that module file:

```
/// <reference path="relative_path_to_cypto_folder/index.d.ts" />
```

Alternatively, you can also use "types" attribute instead of "path", since you're referencing a typings definition inside node_modules/@types:

```
/// <reference types="crypto-js" />
```

After that you can use your code exactly as it is:

```
/// <reference types="crypto-js" />

import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';


var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("It works"), key,
    {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
    keySize: 128 / 8,
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

console.log('Encrypted :' + encrypted);
console.log('Key :' + encrypted.key);
console.log('Salt :' + encrypted.salt);
console.log('iv :' + encrypted.iv);
console.log('Decrypted : ' + decrypted);
console.log('utf8 = ' + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Comment: hi jpavel, if i want to store the encrypted data in db means, how i can able to do?

Comment: What is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: thank you for your reply. Stored encypted password in db sucessfully. one more doubt crypto.lib.WordArray.random(32).toString() in this line getting error as Property 'lib' does not exists on type 'Hashes'.

Comment: @jpavel Hi I am getting different values for both decrypted text and plain text

Comment: can I send `encrypted ` to nodeJS service?

Comment: My node knowledge is not that good, but I do think you can send it to nodejs (as to any other language). But setting up the encryption parameters correctly is crucial for this setup to work so you can decrypt it on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const encryptedMessage = (data: string):any => { var result=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(data), key,
    {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return result.toString();
}

export const decryptedMessage = (encrypted: string):any => {
    var result= CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
//----
//This is how is used it!!
Or in the above example

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("It works"), key,
    {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
    keySize: 128 / 8,
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
//---This is how you extract the encrypted and decrypted strings
console.log('Encrypted :' + encrypted).toString();;
console.log('Decrypted :' + encrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```