# failed to do AES encryption in angular5

Tags: angular5

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671267/encrypt-the-string-in-typescript-and-decrypt-in-c-sharp-using-advanced-encryptio) to create an AES encryption in angular5.

First I installed below modules in my angular5 app

```
npm install crypto-js --save
npm install @types/crypto-js --save
```

then in node_modules I added below code

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"
  ]
```

in my component file I added below code

```
/// <reference path="relative_path_to_cypto_folder/index.d.ts" />
```

but it shows following error

```
91% additional chunk assets processingError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/testApp/Web/node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have no need to initialize crypto-js in angular.json file.
just install crypto-js npm and import it where you want to use like this.

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto-js';
```

And use it like this:

For Encryption:

```
  var cipherText = crypto.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(message),key).toString();
```

For Decryption:

```
var message = crypto.AES.decrypt(cipherText,key).toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
```