# CryptoJS and ES5, can't initialize it into browser

Tags: javascript

I'm not exactly a JS fan, expecially of new ES6 funny syntax.
I'm using CryptoJS which I took from
https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Then i try to use it in a html page like this:

```
var f = new CryptoJS();
```

and

```
var f = new CryptoJS().constructor();
```

but I get

> VM1118:1 Uncaught TypeError: CryptoJS is not a constructor
> at :1:9

I wanted to use it like every old js is used but looks like you have to use one of those funny js syntax things like include or so.

I need to use AES likes this and I miss only the initialization:
[Encrypt in javascript and decrypt in C# with AES algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474899/encrypt-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-c-sharp-with-aes-algorithm)

How can I use it in js in the browser?

Comment: CryptoJS doesn't have a constructor by design (see [docs](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/)), as all its methods can be called as static methods; can you share a link to the source upon which you're basing your implicit claim otherwise? "*looks like you have to use one of those funny js syntax things like include or so.*" Can you also point to a source which backs up this notion? The [CryptoJS README](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#usage-without-requirejs) illustrates that using this in-browser is possible, without the use of `require()` provided by Node.js

Comment: A  pity the only file in that repo is core.js and no crypto-js.js exists at all. I would have gladly followed the guide

Comment: I'm not seeing any ES6 specific code. Your error message says it all. `CryptoJS` looks like an Object to me. So, you don't create a `new` instance of it. It's a single instance already. If `CryptoJS` did have a constructor it would be available like `CryptoJS.constructor`, which you'll notice is not a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CryptoJS' docs](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/) make no mention of any instance methods that you would need to construct an instance of it with `new`, as you seem to be attempting.

> How can I use it in js in the browser?

Exactly described in its [README](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#usage-without-requirejs); just include `crypto-js.js` or `crypto-js-min.js` before invoking its (always-)static methods:

```js
// Encrypt
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123').toString();

// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');
var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(originalText);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A  pity the only file in that repo is core.js and no crypto-js.js exists at all. I would have gladly followed the guide

Comment: The repo is source code, it's not supposed to contain the final products - you use the source code to *build* `crypto-js.js` or `crypto-js-min.js`. If you aren't interested in compiling it yourself, pull it from a trusted CDN like [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js).

Comment: so well. you were right, but i had to run npm view crypto-js dist.tarball to get the tarball from npm. What a whole crappy system we have today to develop.

Thank you anyway